# How to increase variable by (x) units every second and then use variable with Date() to determine how many units since first of month

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the sake of simplicity, lets say I have to build a page that is continuously updating and displaying how many puppies, kittens and rats are being born per second. Like a counter or timer.

I also have to display how many puppies, kittens and rats have been born since 6am and since the start of the month.

What I can't figure out is how to determine how many puppies, kittens and rats have been born since 6am and since the star of the month using Date() and have that amount continuously update.

**HTML**

```
<section id="s01">
    <h1>if 3 puppies are born every second</h1>
    <b id="badge01" class="now">0</b> puppies have been born so far.<br>
    <b class="morning">?</b> puppies have been born since this 6 a.m. morning.<br>
    <b class="month">?</b> puppies have been born since the first of this month.
</section>

<section id="s02">
    <h1>if 5 kittens are born every second</h1>
    <b id="badge02" class="now">0</b> kittens have been born so far.<br>
    <b class="morning">?</b> kittens have been born since this 6 a.m. morning.<br>
    <b class="month">?</b> kittens have been born since the first of this month.
</section>

<section id="s03">
    <h1>if 7 rats are born every second</h1>
    <b id="badge03" class="now">0</b> rats have been born so far.<br>
    <b class="morning">?</b> rats have been born since this 6 a.m. morning.<br>
    <b class="month">?</b> rats have been born since the first of this month.
</section>
```

**JS**

```
var now = new Date();
var dayOfMonth = now.getDate();

setInterval(function () {
    // 3 puppies born every second
    $('#badge01').html(parseInt($('#badge01').html()) + 3);
    // 5 kittens born every second 
    $('#badge02').html(parseInt($('#badge02').html()) + 5);
    // 7 rats born every second
    $('#badge03').html(parseInt($('#badge03').html()) + 7);
}, 1);
```

My JSFiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/gJy4x/6/ (I'm new to JS so please bear with me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by finding the times now, at 6am and the first of the month:

```
var start = new Date(),
    sixAM = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDate(), 6),
    first = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), 1);
```

then, in your interval loop find the seconds that have passed since those times:

```
var now = new Date(),
    secondsFromStart = (now - start)/1000,
    secondsFromSixAM = (now - sixAM)/1000,
    secondsFromFirst = (now - first)/1000;
```

after that you can just push the values into the html (using Math.floor to round down).

See updated fiddle at - http://jsfiddle.net/gJy4x/7/

Comment: I updated your fiddle a bit- thanks! going to poke around the code for a while

Comment: Cool! a general thing I thought was that the secondsFromSixAM may be negative (from midnight till 6am).  Maybe changing it to secondsFromMidnight with the title "puppies born today" might work better.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle with this: midnight = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDate(), 0),

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle with your 12am suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/gJy4x/32/ not only that I made some changes to allow for decimals. I'm working on a project that will feature many of these 'second by second' timer thingys :) Do you have any suggestions as to how I could best optimize this script so its more DRY-ish?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, the second argument to `setInterval()` is in milliseconds. So you want that value to be 1000, not 1.

Assuming 5 kittens every second (*I like kittens!*).

**How many kittens born since 6AM today?**

```
// Cache date object
var now = new Date();

// Give me milliseconds!
var six = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 6);

// Time now
var timeNow = now.getTime();

// Convert milliseconds to seconds
// Since it's in floating point, we'll round it.
var difference = Math.round((timeNow - six) / 1000);

// Woot, kittens!
var totalKittens = difference * 5;
```

**How many kittens born since the beginning of the month?**

Same idea! Instead of using `six`, we'll use:

```
var monthBegin = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth());
```

You can omit the day. The beginning of the month is implied. How do I know that?

In the docs:

> If at least two arguments are supplied, missing arguments are either
>   set to 1 (if date is missing) or 0 for all others.

You should learn more about the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Ah you're right. Sorry about that - I may have missed your edit then. I'm new to SO haha. I'll correct it right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get seconds since 6am today:

```
function secsSince6am() {
  var now = new Date();
  var earlier = new Date(+now);
  earlier.setHours(6,0,0,0);
  return Math.round((now - earlier)/1000);
}
```

But that will only work **after** 6am. If you want the time since 6am yesterday for the interval between midnight and 6am, you can do:

```
function secsSince6am() {
  var now = new Date();
  var earlier = new Date(+now);
  earlier.setHours(6,0,0,0);
  var diff = Math.round((now - earlier)/1000);
  return diff < 0? diff + 8.64e4 : diff;
}
```

To get seconds since the start of the month:

```
function secsSinceStartOfMonth() {
  var now = new Date();
  var earlier = new Date(+now);
  earlier.setDate(1);
  earlier.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  return Math.round((now - earlier)/1000);
}
```

Comment: I like your use of round() as well as setDate()! I'm curious, why did you do pass +now to new Date()? Also - what's the reason for adding 8.64e4?

Comment: When a Date object is supplied as an argument to `new Date()`, it is first converted to a string, then the string is parsed to create a date object. IE gets it wrong for years 0 - 99, assuming they are two digit years from the 20th century. Using `+now` converts it to a time value, which is used correctly everywhere. It may not matter in this case, but it does sometimes. Adding 8.64e4 is only for the period midnight to 0600 to return the seconds since 0600 the previous day (if that is a required). Otherwise, use the first function and deal with -ve values for 0000 to 0600 some other way. :-)

Comment: Interesting. So using the year 1999 in a date string will get parsed into an incorrect time value by IE? If so - do you happen to know which version of IE? Because that sounds really bad.

Comment: No, I'm saying that where a Date object is in the range 1-99, then `new Date(date)` will create a date in the range 1901-1999. It happens with all versions of IE up to 9 at least, I haven't tested 10.